# How should I set initialise instance variables on an ApplicationRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, initialization

My app creates a `QuoteRequest` object and upon save of that object to the db I want it to create a `Quote.new` object (`QuoteRequest` `has_one` `Quote`). In a new `Quote` instance I want to set some instance variables, which various methods related to a Watir crawler will use, then the result of that Watir crawl & scrape will #save thus persist the Quote object to the db.

I would like to set the `Quote` instance variables in an `initialize` method as soon as the object is created, but this is creating issues with the fact that it inherits from `ApplicationRecord` this there's an initialization conflict.

What is the correct way to instantiate an `ApplicationRecord` object with variables, without conflicting with the Rails library initialization code?

Comment: Both really helpful answers, thanks guys. Wish I could accept two answers, but as I cannot I felt compelled to accept M. Simon Borgs's due to the length of explanation provided, though Vijay's is a perfectly good answer too. Thanks again, Vijay, get you next time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to set one instance variable without any extra logic at initialize then Vijay's answer is a good one. However you can have more flexibility than just being restricted to `attr` methods.

As with all Ruby, you can always take advantage of `super` if you're maintaining the right interface to the super method. `ActiveRecord::Base#initialize` only takes one optional argument, a `hash` of attributes and values. It also yields itself to a block if a block is given. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L313

So if you wanted to set an instance variable at initialization without also defining any public access methods, you can:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(attributes = nil, &block)
    @my_var = attributes.delete(:my_var) if attributes
    super
  end
end

quote = Quote.new(my_var: 'value')
quote.instance_variable_get(:@my_var) # => "value"
```

You can also perform more complex operations. Assume you have `User has_many :posts` and `Post belongs_to :user`, `User` has a `:name` and `Post` has a `:title`.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(attributes = nil, &block)
    title = attributes.delete(:first_post_title) if attributes
    super
    posts.build(title: "#{name}'s first post: #{title}") if title
  end
end

user = User.new(first_post_title: 'Hello, world!', name: 'Matz')
user.posts.first # => #<Post:xxxxxxxxxxx title: "Matz's first post: Hello, world!">
```

Hopefully that demonstrates how flexible you can be even with `ActiveRecord` objects, and sometimes callbacks are a little too complicated in implementation and restrictive in use when `super` can work just fine and even better when used appropriately.

Comment: @m-simon-borg, I'm still struggling to instantiate with an `expected 0..1` arguments error, I'm doing exactly as you suggest above in the initialize method but with the following variables; `@username = attributes.delete(:username) if attributes` and `@password = attributes.delete(:password) if attributes` and `@url = attributes.delete(:url) if attributes` then calling `super` after variable declaration.

Comment: @jbk What does your code look like? What else does the `ArgumentError` say? `expected 0..1, received ???` If your method declaration is `def initialize(attributes = nil, &block)` then you should call `super` with no arguments. Make sure also that your `Quote.new` call is using hash syntax like you would otherwise e.g. `Quote.new(username: "...", password: "...", url: "...")`. If you want to put it in a Gist and link to it here I'd be happy to look. Also Vijay's answer could be all that you need in your case

Comment: Excuse me @m-simon-borg, a daft syntax error at my end, now this initialize method with super is working beautifully  Thanks.

Comment: @jbk no problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

For the properties of `Quote` you don't want to save in DB, create `attr_reader` (or `attr_accessor`). Suppose your Watir method needs `var1` and `var2` objects, then your `Quote` should look like this:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  attr_reader :var1, :var2
end
```

And then in `after_create` callback of `QuoteRequest` you should simply pass these variables as key-value pair like any other property.

```
obj1 = Var1.new
obj2 = Var2.new
quote = Quote.new(var1: obj1, var2: obj2, ....)`
```

Now you can access these by calling `quote.var1` and `quote.var2`. Calling `save` on `quote` would persist all the properties which have corresponding columns in db except `var1`, `var2`.

Comment: in the above context, would 'var1' & 'var2' on 'Quote.save' be persisted to the db had I have created columns for them?

Comment: If you have column for var1 and var2 then you don't need to add this line: 
 `attr_reader :var1, :var2`

Comment: aha, so id a column is defined on the model schema then rails automatically adds `attr_accessor`?

Comment: Yes. if var1 and var2 are objects instead of native datatypes then this guide would help you http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html